# How to read complete exif and tiff info of image in ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, image-processing, ios7, exif

i am trying to extract exif info from image .

```
UIImage *pImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0011.JPG"];
NSData* pngData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pImage, 1.0);

CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)pngData, NULL);
NSDictionary *metadata = (__bridge NSDictionary *) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
NSLog(@"exif %@" , metadata);
```

i got following metadata info

```
exif {
    ColorModel = RGB; <br>
    Depth = 8; <br>
    Orientation = 1; <br>
    PixelHeight = 1936;<br>
    PixelWidth = 2592;<br>
    "{Exif}" =     {
        ColorSpace = 1;<br>
        PixelXDimension = 2592;<br>
        PixelYDimension = 1936;<br>
    };
    "{JFIF}" =     {<br>
        DensityUnit = 0;<br>
        JFIFVersion =         (<br>
            1,<br>
            1<br>
        );
        XDensity = 1;<br>
        YDensity = 1;<br>
    };
    "{TIFF}" =     {<br>
        Orientation = 1;<br>
    };
}<br>
```

But when i check the image using exif data viewer or preview app following info i got.

```
Aperture Value: 2.526<br>
Brightness Value: 1.897<br>
Color Space: sRGB<br>
Components Configuration: 1, 2, 3, 0<br>
Date Time Digitized: 20-Dec-2013 1:33:31 PM<br>
Date Time Original: 20-Dec-2013 1:33:31 PM<br>
Exif Version: 2.2.1<br>
Exposure Mode: Auto exposure<br>
Exposure Program: Normal program<br>
Exposure Time: 1/15<br>
Flash: No flash function<br>
FlashPix Version: 1.0<br>
FNumber: 2.4
Focal Length: 4.28<br>
Focal Length In 35mm Film: 35<br>
ISO Speed Ratings: 125<br>
Metering Mode: Pattern<br>
Pixel X Dimension: 2,592<br>
Pixel Y Dimension: 1,936<br>
Scene Capture Type: Standard<br>
Sensing Method: One-chip color area sensor<br>
Shutter Speed Value: 3.907
Subject Area: 1295, 967, 699, 696
White Balance: Auto white balance<br>
Regions: {
    HeightAppliedTo = 1936;<br>
    RegionList =     (
                {
            ConfidenceLevel = 326;<br>
            FaceID = 3;<br>
            Height = "0.172";<br>
            Timestamp = 956449648;<br>
            Type = Face;<br>
            Width = "0.128";
            X = "0.542";<br>
            Y = "0.426";<br>
        }
    );
    WidthAppliedTo = 2592; <br>
}
```

any suggestion how to extract full exif data on ios ....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're round-tripping this through `UIImage` and converting to a `NSData` via `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, which will strip lots of interesting information. Just load the `NSData` directly:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_0011" ofType:@"JPG"];
NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)pngData, NULL);
NSDictionary *metadata = CFBridgingRelease(CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL));
NSLog(@"exif %@" , metadata);
CFRelease(source);
```

BTW, don't forget the "[Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029)", namely that Core Foundation functions with `Create` or `Copy` in their name are transferring ownership to you, and you're responsible for releasing the objects, yourself. For example, you can use `__bridge_transfer` or `CFBridgingRelease` to transfer ownership of the source properties dictionary to ARC. And you can explicitly `CFRelease` of the `CGImageSourceRef`.

Comment: I do it this way and I still see the limited exif data. My image that I download into an NSData container is a .THM file. Do you have any idea what my issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

```
CGImageSourceRef myImageSource;

myImageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, NULL);

CFDictionaryRef props = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(myImageSource,0, NULL);

NSDictionary *exif = [(__bridge NSDictionary *)props objectForKey : (NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];
NSString *dateTimeString = [exif objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal];


CFRelease(props);
CFRelease(myImageSource);
```